# How to create nested dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I want to create nested dictionary. and my input will be

```
P0licy Details :Policy No  Company Code  Issue Date  Due Date T6266207 03 I 09/30/2011 I 06/30/2017  T6706735 03 I CURRENT I 06/02/2017 I
```

I want to output like this.and programatically i want to remove I symbol in between 09/30/2011 I 06/30/2017

```
{
 "P0licy Details": {
"Policy No": ["T6266207", "T670673"],
" Company Code": ["03", "03"],
" Issue Date": ["09/30/2011", "06/30/2017 "],
"Due Date": ["CURRENT", "06/02/2017"]
}
  }
```

Comment: Can you give a little more clarity on the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this..

```
`inputt="P0licy Details :Policy No  Company Code  Issue Date  Due Date              T6266207 03 I 09/30/2011 I 06/30/2017  T6706735 03 I CURRENT I 06/02/2017 I"

s=inputt#.replace(" I ","")
my_list=s.split(" ")  
indexq=len(my_list) - 1 - my_list[::-1].index('Date')
final=my_list[indexq+1:]
for items in final:
if items=="I":
   #final.pop(index(items))
    final.remove(items)  `
stringa=str(str(my_list[0]+ " "+ my_list[1])+": {" +str(my_list[2])+":" )
print(stringa)
```